# Callback in Dart when the page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dart, polymer

You may know that I totally fell in love with Dart and Polymer and once again, I have a question addressing those two technologies.

My application is a fairly compex polymer app written in Dart. There are some sort of "pages" whereas a page is shown once the user performed an action. The pages contain various types of content and the number of items can reach from zero to a few hundreds.

To enhance the user experience I've build a loader which you can register elements at and once all registered elements loaded, the page is shown. This works and feels pretty amazing but it's way to complicated to make sure to react on all the different states which can occur and overall I am not that happy with the loader thingy.

Thus I wanted to ask if there is anything in Dart or Polymer which helps me to show a loading indicator as long as not everything is fully loaded and once it is done, it hides the loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an HTML/CSS-only loading indicator and style it so that it becomes hidden when the `unresolved` attribute is removed from the body. See https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html#preventing-fouc

Comment: I always thought, unresolved can only be used for the initial page load... So, just to make sure I got you right. When the user hits a button which cause some content change, I add unresolved to the very top element of these new data, e.g. to an element called `page` and unresolved will be removed automatically once everything is loaded? How about ongoing ajax requests which then causes addional data to be loaded? I really try to understand the mechanism of unresolved, but I just cannot see, this working.

Comment: Honestly I didn't understand your question well and I just made a wild guess. `unresolved` doesn't seem the right thing for your problem. Unresolved is only to indicate Polymer has finished initializing all components. There is no universal way to know when all is done. What you can do is to create a loading indicator component which listens for events. When you start a long running operation you fire an event to indicate to the loading indicator to show itself, when your ajax call finished you fire another event to indicate the loading indicator should remove itself.

Comment: I am esentially doing it that way, but there is more than just one ajax request. I got multiple requests, tons of large images, complex SVGs which might take a while to construct the HTML code for and more. Thus it's a quite a lot of work to detect when everything is done, which is the reason why I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand. To elaborate on that approach. You could use a queue in the loading indicator and just add all Futures you get for the requests you make and as long as there are uncompleted futures in the queue, the loading indicator stays visible. When all futures are completed it hides/removes itself.

Comment: Great idea to use futures here! I'm definitely give it a try.

Comment: Although I didnt make use of the `unresolved` tag, I accept the answer since the idea with using Futures was amazing. I'm using combinations of `Future.doWhile`, `Future.wait` and `Completer` to synchronize everything. No matter if it's an ajax request, a DOM update or loading images. It's super easy and a very clean way.